# Returning partial incomplete results from a method that threw an exception

Tags: java, exception

I'd like some feedback on a situation where:

A method constructs an object, but some of the work done while constructing it might fail. This will lead to an object that is missing some data. I want to give the user of this method the ability to handle the object if complete but also handle the object if incomplete while also being able to handle the exception thrown.

Use Case:

I'm reading a file from disk into a POJO and some of the file attributes like date created can throw an exception while being read from the Operating System. In that case I'm throwing a custom exception but I also want the user to be able to handle that incomplete file representation (POJO).

My solution:

I used a custom exception that wraps the thrown exception and the incomplete object.

My code:

```
public FileDto getFromFile(File f) throws IncompleteFileDtoException {

    FileDto dto = new FileDto();
    dto.setName(f.getName());
    dto.setPath(f.getAbsolutePath());
    dto.setDirectory(f.isDirectory());
    dto.setSize(f.length());
    dto.setModifiedAt(f.lastModified());

    try {
        BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(f.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);
        dto.setCreatedAt(attr.creationTime().toMillis());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new IncompleteFileDtoException("Unable to transform " +f.getAbsolutePath() + " to DTO.", e, dto );
    }
    return dto;
}

public static class IncompleteFileDtoException extends Exception
{
    private FileDto fileDto;

    public IncompleteFileDtoException(String message, Exception e, FileDto fileDto)
    {
        super(message,e);
        this.fileDto = fileDto;
    }

    public FileDto getFileDto() {
        return fileDto;
    }
}
```

What negative effects could this code have ?

Answer (score 0):

I offer you to use `Builder` pattern. Do create `FileDtoBuilder` and put it into exception. When you read file successfully, the do create `FileDto` instance from existed `FileDtoBuilder`.

**Gang Of Four Design Patterns**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: That sounds like an interesting addition indeed. What I can see as a benefit from it is that the Builder delegates the object construction process (which might be heavy) to the user of the method, who if deems it un-necessary, won't construcdt the object and won't use the resources, correct ?

Comment: That is correct. It is very useful for many cases: e.g. like your, when you have problem in the middle of object init, or e.g. when you wan to build unmodifiable object with many final parameters (instead of using constructor with all these parameters). "Gang Of Four Design Pattern" is the very good book about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your example only contained one value that might lead to a problem but as soon as you have multiple values you end up with quiet complicated code, because you have to keep the information if such an exception should be thrown.

Personally a better approach might be to just set fitting default values (if not just a null) if the processing failed but it's OK for the initialization of that particular value. And if it's OK that a value can be null you can just the whole exception-throwing. If you need to know if there was a problem during setup, add a flag in that object that gives the information if something failed that can be cheecked. That would also allow you to pass the object around without losing that information in subsequent classes, etc.

In short: Exception should only indicate exceptional situations, i.e. that an object can't be used and not to indicate expected situations

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ipapaste/d7350cd071e72ab01800b8b0d076c8cc

Would this work better I guess ? I'm sinking the exception and instead return a result wrapper around the object with metadata about it's creation.